# angularjs - building a large app - one place for all the routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Building a large `angularjs` app. The idea is to use something like require.js to lazy-load other modules, or something similar. But the question is, do I have to create a large route.js file that contains all the routes to the other modules, or should I, inside each module, define its `routeprovider` and then somehow register that to the main `app.js` file? Does `require.js` make that posible, or do I have to find some `angularjs` hack.

Current file structure is:

```
- frontend
    - css
    - js
        - lib             // containg angular.js
        - app.js          // containg the main angular.module
        - route.js        // routeProvider for the app.js
        - modules         // folder of modules
              - module1
                    - module1.js
              - module2
                    - module2.js
```

Or:

```
- frontend
    - css
    - js
        - lib             // containg angular.js
        - app.js          // containg the main angular.module
        - modules         // folder of modules
              - module1
                    - module1.js
                    - route1.js
              - module2
                    - module2.js 
                    - route2.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either way. I tried using a configuration defined in a json file and load the modules (I used angular-route-segment as you can have modules and submodules navigation).

One gotcha was, after lazy loading the controllers, you have to register controller by calling `$controllerProvider.register`. This is true for directives and others as well.

You can also define the route before the navigation and navigate to that route.

I have tried all this using `requirejs`.

Please check the github project [here](https://github.com/madhured/AngularLazyLoading) and let me know if anything.

Comment: the file webApp/js/shell/config/config.js, it seems that if you had more modules, you would add them in this file. Basically all the routes in one place, but lazy-loaded, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to register them all in one place. That's the nice thing about Angular: it allows you to assemble components based on what you are loading and then handles resolving them in the correct order when you're ready.

On our large application, we'd have `module1` or `module2` register it's own routes. You just need to get at the main module. There are a few ways to do it:

1. Simply create a global reference to it, something like:

   ```
   var app = anglar.module("myMainModule", []);
   ```
2. Reference it later, i.e. if you call module without the dependencies it will reference the existing:

   ```
   var appLocal = angular.module("myMainModule");
   ```

Either way you can have a `main.js` that sets up the app, then in your module reference it (either via calling module again or via a global variable) and then set up the routes for that module there.

Comment: do you then use routeProvider or controllerProvider to let angular know which one to load, or how does angular know that module1 file exists.

Comment: The master file will include main.js and module1.js. In module1.js the config block is used to grab the $routeProvider and configure the routes. It knows it exists because you are in the context of module 1 so you have to have some "master" process request it.

Comment: That means you would have to load the JS files of every possible section of the application in your master file, correct?